# react js multiple image upload with preview

Tags: javascript, reactjs

using react js I need multiple image upload with preview I tried with below code is not working it showing me error in console

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to set the 'value' property on
>   'HTMLInputElement': This input element accepts a filename, which may
>   only be programmatically set to the empty string.

```
uploadImage(e){
    var numFiles = e.target.files.length; 
    for (var i = 0, numFiles = e.target.files.length; i < numFiles; i++){ 
            var file = e.target.files[i];
            if(!file.type.match('image'))
            continue;
            var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e) {
            setOfImages.push({
              fileName:file.name,
              image:e.target.result.split(',')[1]
            });
            for(var j = 0; j<setOfImages.length; j++) {
                $('.placeholder-blk').prepend('<div class="image-placeholder"><img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'+ setOfImages[j].image +'" /></div>');
            }
            console.log(setOfImages);
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
}
<input type="file" name="image-uploder" id="image-uploder" className="file-loader" onChange={this.uploadImage.bind(this)} multiple />
```

Comment: This makes no sense `$('.placeholder-blk').remove();` then subsequently try to  prepend to that? It's gone.

Comment: And here only the first file? `var file = e.target.files[0];`  Did you mean to process the files `var numFiles = e.target.files.length;
for (var i = 0, numFiles = e.target.files.length; i < numFiles; i++) {
  var file = e.target.files[i];
  ..
}`

Comment: yes i can also upload the multiple image files also @MarkSchultheiss

Comment: Ref here how to do it raw: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications

Comment: thank u @MarkSchultheiss I got output but when prepend the the div it duplicating the div now I edited the code above one updated one

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding the value to the state and populate the name from the state.
Something like

```
<input type="file" name={this.state.setOfImages} id="image-uploder" className="file-loader" onChange={this.uploadImage.bind(this)} multiple />
```

and inside your function populate the state.

```
this.setState({setOfImages: JSON.stringify(setOfImages)})
```

something like this.

```
export class Demo extends React.Component{
constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        setOfImages : []
    }
}
setOfImages(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
        setOfImages: ["hello", "hi"]
    })
}
render(){
    return (
        <div>
            <input value={this.state.setOfImages}/>
            <button onClick={this.setOfImages.bind(this)}/>
        </div>
    )
}
}
```

Now first the input will be populated with empty array . When you click the button the state will change by setting the setOfImages = ["hello", "hi"] and making the input value set to those values.

Answer (score 0):

This makes no sense `$('.placeholder-blk').remove();` then subsequently try to prepend to that? It's gone.

And here only the first file?

`var file = e.target.files[0];`

Did you mean to process the files

```
var numFiles = e.target.files.length; 
for (var i = 0, numFiles = e.target.files.length; i < numFiles; i++) 
{ var file = e.target.files[i]; .. }
```

Ref here how to do it raw: [developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/)